# Find all missing dates between two dates in excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have over 500,000 rows of data in a sheet.  In column D of that sheet, each row has a date between Sep 18 2016, and May 31, 2021.  I want to use an array formula to list all the dates between those dates i just gave, that are not represented in column D.  **Edit:** I would like to use a formula, because my end date of May 31, 2021 does change to a later date every month.

Is this possible in excel with predefined functions, or will I need to write a macro? I'd post what I started with if i could, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Pretty complicated in Excel 2016. I'd suggest either the filter method suggested by @teylyn, or using VBA or Power Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer but will require you to insert a column after the date column (unless date is the last column). The end result is:

[image]

the image shows 1) the inserted column B into the worksheet, 2) column C is the start and end date of the range you want and 3) a spill formula in column E that gives you the missing dates. The formula (for this example) is:

`=FILTER(IFNA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1),A1:B31,2,FALSE),SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1)),IFNA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1),A1:B31,2,FALSE),SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1))<>0,"no missing dates")`

Explanation:

`SEQUENCE()` creates an array of dates from the date range in column C

`VLOOKUP()` using SEQUENCE returns the blank (zero) value from column B if there is a match

`IFNA()` if VLOOKUP fails (that means date is missing) it will return the missing date (SEQUENCE again)

`FILTER()` returns only missing dates

Comment: this may be shortened with the Let function to:  `=LET(dateMissing,LET(dateSearch,SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1),(IFNA(VLOOKUP(dateSearch,A1:B15,2,FALSE),dateSearch))),FILTER(dateMissing,dateMissing,"no missing dates"))`

Comment: Your first answer nails it.  The one using the LET function gives me a name error, but your other one works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I found that the solution works in a test sheet, but gives many false positives in my actual sheet.  The only differences are that the data is on a different sheet than the start and end dates and it's a bigger range.  I've adapted the formula to be =FILTER(IFNA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1),raw!D2:E517462,2,FALSE),SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1)),IFNA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1),raw!D2:E517462,2,FALSE),SEQUENCE(+C2-C1+1,1,C1,1))<>0,"no missing dates")

Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: I'm wondering if the false positives are because some of your raw data are not dates but text of dates. Your adjusted formula looks correct, and I couldn't duplicate your issue when I moved the formula on to a different sheet, and created 500K random dates on a separate data sheet (including deleting 3 dates from the test missing date range).

Comment: My apologies, I think `LET()` is later than excel 2016. I wasn't even sure `FILTER()` was going to work...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with an array formula with Excel 2016 will be quite involved.

Why not use an easier approach that doesn't involve complicated formulas or VBA?

Create a list of dates from the start date to the end date. In the next column, use a Match formula to find the date in your data. You could use a formula that returns a TRUE/FALSE result, like

```
=isnumber(Match(A1,$Z:$Z,0))
```

If the result of the match is a number, i.e. the date is found, then the formula returns TRUE, otherwise FALSE.

Now you just need to filter the list of dates to show only the rows with "FALSE" in the formula column.

That's a lot faster than writing VBA or complex arrays.

**Note**: this will only work if your dates are dates only, not date/time values. If you have date/time values (which show decimals if formatted as General), then you need a helper column in your data source that extracts only the date. Then run the Match() on that date column.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: This will work, but is not ideal as I add to the database periodically. That final date of May 31, 2021 date will soon be June 30, 2021.  But I do appreciate your creative approach to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a macro for this.  It's not the best as it uses direct cell references, but I added comments below to explain everything so perhaps it will be of use to someone, someday.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'on a button click, loop through list of dates on one worksheet to 
'find missing ones between two dates specified on another worksheet

Dim lr As Long
Dim r As Range, dateslist As Range
Dim startD As Date, endD As Date, da As Date
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim frontSht As Worksheet, rawSht As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
'the sheet where we want missing dates displayed:
Set frontSht = wb.Sheets("frontPage") 
'the sheet where our dated data rows live:
Set rawSht = wb.Sheets("rawData") 'the sheet where our dated data rows live

'Cell B1 on the front sheet has the start date of the range we care about:
startD = frontSht.Range("B1").Value 
'Cell B2 has the end date of that range:                             
endD = frontSht.Range("B2").Value

'Get the last row with data's number:
lr = rawSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 

'define the date list to look through and include the blank cell below our last date: 
Set dateslist = rawSht.Range("D2:D" & (lr + 1)) 

'no screen updating during the following loops:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

'The list of missing dates we are about to generate will start in this cell:
frontSht.Range("A7").Activate 

'For each date in our desired range, loop thru dates in the data looking for a match
'If we find one, exit the inner loop and move to the next date in our range.
'If we don't find one and reach the blank box at the end of the data range,
'write that date for which no data exists into our 'missing dates' list.
For da = startD To endD
    For Each r In dateslist
        If da = r.Value Then Exit For
        If IsEmpty(r) Then
            ActiveCell.Value = da
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Next r
Next da

End Sub
```

If you run this macro on a large data set like mine (4.5-year range and up to 500,000 rows to look through for each day in that range) it will take some time.  I'm sure there are better ways to do this. Feel free to enlight us if you know a better way.

Comment: For your inner loop instead of looping through all raw dates, do whatever is the VBA equivalent of `SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(raw dates)))`. Also start the inner loop at the "last found" row +1 (I think). I'm thinking this would drop you from 250K inner loop iterations per outer loop down to maybe a little more than 1...

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER((SEQUENCE(A13-A2+1,1,MIN(A:A))),NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH((SEQUENCE(A13-A2+1,1,A2)),A2:A13,0))))
```

List of dates in col A with a header, replace the three instances of A13 with the last cell with data.

This creates a new list of dates that would include all dates, then filters it down based on what is not included in the dates in column A.